# Another form of the divergence theorem

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, line-integrals, divergence-theorem

The task is to calculate an integral of the form
$$\iint_s x dydz + ydxdz +zdxdy. $$
The text I'm studying says this is just another form of the famed divergence theorem,
$$\iint_s F.n \,ds = \iiint_v \operatorname{div} F \,dV,$$
where $F$ is simply $(x, y, z)$, so that the value of the integral is
$$\iiint (1+1+1) dV = 3V.$$

The question is why is the original integral equal to the divergence integral?
More generally, why is it true that
$$\iint_s  Pdzdy+ Qdxdz +Rdxdy = 
\iint_s (P, Q, R)\cdot n \,ds?$$

Answer (score 1):

It is indeed true that
$$(F\cdot \hat{n})\,dA = F_x dy\wedge dz + F_y dz\wedge dx + F_z dx\wedge dy.$$
(Be careful about the orientation of each term!)

This follows from the fact that
$$\hat{n}_x dA = dy\wedge dz$$
on the surface of $S$, and similarly for the other coordinates; you can prove this by direct calculation on a coordinate chart, but probably the easiest way is to notice that the Hodge stars of both term,
$$\hat{n}_x (\hat{n}_x dx + \hat{n}_y dy + \hat{n}_z dz), \qquad dx$$
agree on vectors $\alpha \hat{n}$ orthogonal to $S$.